# How to use apply function once for each unique factor value

Tags: r

I'm trying on some commands on the R-studio built-in databse, ChickWeight. The data looks as follows.

```
   weight Time Chick Diet
1      42    0     1    1
2      51    2     1    1
3      59    4     1    1
4      64    6     1    1
5      76    8     1    1
6      93   10     1    1
7     106   12     1    1
8     125   14     1    1
9     149   16     1    1
10    171   18     1    1
11    199   20     1    1
12    205   21     1    1
13     40    0     2    1
14     49    2     2    1
15     58    4     2    1
```

Now what I would like to do is to simply output the difference between the chicken-weight for the "Chick" column for time 0 and 21 (last time value). I.e the weight the chick has put on.

I've been trying `tapply(ChickWeight$weight, ChickWeight$Chick, function(x) x[length(x)] - x[1])`. But this of course applies the value to all rows.

How do I make it so that it applies only once for each unique Chick-value?

Comment: Can you show the expected output? Do you want a column or just a number

Comment: In the example, the last time value is 21, but you mentioned `18` as the last?

Comment: My bad. I have edited it now so it says 21 in the text. I would like a simple vector return.

Comment: Do you need to add a column?  Suppose if Time=0 or Time=21 is not present in one of the factors, what will be the desired output?  For example in Chick 2.

Comment: Also, is it the difference between the max and min values rather than just 0 and 21?

Comment: Well then it would simply take the latest available time, but this is again just an exercise for me. But good issue.

Comment: Well, in your case it would be desirable to simply take the last value minus the first value, irrespective of time-stamp. However in real application a time-stamp check would be preferable, Again this is just an exercise for me. I've commented your solution below

Comment: I am using the max and min value of Time in case the dataset is not ordered by Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need a single value per each 'factor' column (assuming that 'Chick', and 'Diet' are the factor columns)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Diff= abs(weight[Time==21]-weight[Time==0])) ,.(Chick, Diet)]
```

and If we need to create a column

```
 setDT(df1)[,  Diff:= abs(weight[Time==21]-weight[Time==0]) ,.(Chick, Diet)]
```

I noticed that in the example `Time = 21` is not found in the Chick No:2, may be in that case, we need one of the number

```
setDT(df1)[, {tmp <- Time %in% c(0,21)
  list(Diff= if(sum(tmp)>1) abs(diff(weight[tmp])) else weight[tmp]) } ,
                by =  .(Chick, Diet)]
#    Chick Diet Diff
#1:     1    1  163
#2:     2    1   40
```

---

If we are taking the difference of 'weight' based on the `max` and `min` 'Time' for each group

```
 setDT(df1)[, list(Diff=weight[which.max(Time)]- 
                weight[which.min(Time)]), .(Chick, Diet)]
 #   Chick Diet Diff
 #1:     1    1  163
 #2:     2    1   18
```

Also, if the 'Time' is ordered

```
setDT(df1)[, list(Diff= abs(diff(weight[c(1L,.N)]))), by =.(Chick, Diet)]
```

Using `by` from `base R`

```
  by(df1[1:2], df1[3:4], FUN= function(x) with(x, 
      abs(weight[which.max(Time)]-weight[which.min(Time)])))
  #Chick: 1
  #Diet: 1
  #[1] 163
  #------------------------------------------------------------ 
  #Chick: 2
  #Diet: 1
  #[1] 18
```

Comment: would a solution be possible with only native packages? I would prefer to limit myself to the basics as of now.

Comment: @uncool Do you need the length of the result to be the same as the nrow of the dataset or just summary as I showed in the last output

Comment: Your solution is great! Thank you very much. I'm just wondering if there's a native function that would be applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`:

```
ChickWeight %>%
  group_by(Chick = as.numeric(as.character(Chick))) %>%
  summarise(weight_gain = last(weight) - first(weight), final_time = last(Time))
```

(First and last as suggested by @ulfelder.)

Note that `ChickWeight$Chick` is an ordered factor so without coercing it into numeric the final order looks odd.

Using base R:

```
ChickWeight$Chick <- as.numeric(as.character(ChickWeight$Chick))
tapply(ChickWeight$weight, ChickWeight$Chick, function(x) x[length(x)] - x[1])
```

Comment: dplyr also has `first()` and `last()` functions that allow you to write the third line of the dplyr version as follows: `summarise(weight_gain = last(weight) - first(weight), final_time = last(Time))`.